# Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 while running Java 1.8 on AWS EMR

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, emr

I am trying to run Java 1.8 Map Reduce Job over AWS EMR. I have set compile compliance and JRE version as 1.8. But still its giving following error while running.

Since I am using one stanford API I cannot switch to lower Java versions. Could some one please help me here.

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/neu/mr/cs6750/reducerjoin/ReduceSideJoin : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

Comment: Well obviously you aren't running Java 1.8 at all, you're running some earlier version.

Answer (score -1):

Use this configuration to run EMR with java8. This sets up the hadoop-env i.e., hadoop java environment variable to java8

> [{"configurations":[{"classification":"export","properties":>{"JAVA_HOME":"/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0"}}],"classification":"hadoop->env","properties":{}}]

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html#configuring-java8